# Paw suddenly asks for client certificate

Tags: paw-app

It didn't ask for any client certificate before. But recently I can't use Paw since every time I make a request, it says "The server requires a client certificate"

Anything I can do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to do is to change HTTP Library to NSURLConnection like on the screenshot below and it will keep working as before.

[image]